# php: How to assign an array's values to default table?

Tags: arrays, assign

Here is my code:

```
$table=array("a","b","c","d");
$datas=array("a_1","c_8");

foreach($datas as $x => $data){
    $data=explode("_",$data);
    $keys[$x]=$data[0];
    $vals[$x]=$data[1];
}

$key=implode("</td><td>",$keys);
$val=implode("</td><td>",$vals);

echo"<table><tr><td>".$key."</td></tr><tr><td>".$val."</td></tr></table>";
```

It prints out like this:

```
a   c
1   8
```

But i want this one:

```
a   b   c   d
1       8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the foreach, it's currently only running 2 times, since the $datas Array only has two entrys. Try using the table Array, just like so:

```
$table=array("a","b","c","d");
$datas=array("a_1","c_8");

foreach($table as $x => $tab){

    $var = "";

    foreach($datas as $data){

        $data = explode("_", $data);

        if($data[0]==$tab){
            $var = $data[1];
        }
    }

    $keys[$x]=$tab;
    $vals[$x]=$var;
}

$key=implode("</td><td>",$keys);
$val=implode("</td><td>",$vals);

echo"<table><tr><td>".$key."</td></tr><tr><td>".$val."</td></tr></table>";
```